# VB.Net FileStream Exception File In use by another

Tags: vb.net, exception, filestream

I have VB code that opens an input file and reads it in, manipulates the data as its read and write the the data out to a second file.   I have precised the code below.   When I try to use the same program to open and manipulate the file that was output the first time I get an Error saying the File was in use by another process.

If I rename the file in anyway then retry the task the error does not occur.  As I understood it enclosing the filestream within a USING meant that the filestreams should close be default.  As you will see I have tried to force that but still the issue occurs.

It makes no odds if I close the application and try with a fresh start, the file still triggers and exception.   Most code I have seen tend to discuss the topic using C language and I am not following that.

Suggestions please as I can't see why the file should be in use.
Thank you

```vb
Using destinationFileStream As New FileStream(filename2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    ' Create a buffer to store the read bytes
    Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
    Dim Buffer2(4096) As Byte
    Dim bytesRead As Integer

    ' Process the file byte by byte
    Do
        ' Read a chunk of bytes from the source file
        bytesRead = sourceFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

        ' If bytesRead is 0, we reached the end of the file
        If bytesRead > 0 Then
            ' do things with the data read in and put then in buffer2
            ' Write the bytes to the destination file
            destinationFileStream.Write(Buffer2, 0, bytesRead)
        End If
    Loop While bytesRead > 0
    destinationFileStream.Close()    'redundant code bit because USING forces a close 
End Using
```

Comment: I would use a utility like Sysinternals Handle.exe (or Hanfle64.exe) to see which process keeps the file open. This can happen if, e.g., the file is open in Excel.

Comment: Which one is open? You also have `sourceFileStream` - how is that being handled?

Comment: To clarify further, the output file that the code is writing to seems to be affected (that is left open or in use).  To make matters worse even if the file is moved to another computer it and the software is used on a completely different machine the error occurs.   Rename the file even 1 char and the error doesn't occur.

Comment: Does your code use the output file anywhere else? Also, if you want a 4096 byte buffer then you have to declare it like `Dim buffer(4095) As Byte` because VB.NET uses the last index of the array in the declaration , not the size.

Comment: Also , is the problem with the input file or the output file? I can't tell from the question.

Comment: The buffer is declared before the redacted code segment I posted so that is not an issue.  As stated in my comment the problem is with the output file.  To me this is like VB.NET simply is NOT closing the file despite encapsulating the filestream within a USING statement and further also forcing it to close.    I have seen other posts on this issue but NEVER seen a practical answer yet.